# Prepend dynamic content to multiple elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, styling, prepend

Sure this is an easy one but finding it hard to search for an answer due to not knowing the exact words to search for :/

also if theres a better way of doing this please do tell me ;)

basically I'm generating some div boxes with various contents and titles

so in my html pages I have:

```
<div class="itdSec" data-title="What is This">
    This is a magical div box with some stuff in it
</div>
```

in my js file I have

```
$(".itdSec").prepend("<div class='itdSecTit'>" + this.data("title") + "</div>");
```

The intent is to add a div to the top of that div with the contents of the data-title arribute

the "this" is causing the errors as this is still the main page. and using `$(".itdSec")` in its place returns the first one each time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".itdSec").prepend(function() {
    return "<div class='itdSecTit'>" + $(this).data("title") + "</div>";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="itdSec" data-title="What is This">
    This is a magical div box with some stuff in it
</div>
```

alternatively you can do this:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".itdSec").each(function() {
    $(this).prepend("<div class='itdSecTit'>" + $(this).data("title") + "</div>");
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="itdSec" data-title="What is This">
  This is a magical div box with some stuff in it
</div>
```

Comment: You have two identical jsfiddle links there ;)

Comment: @ngmir Whops :) I changed it to the new stackoverflow snippets.

Answer (score 2):

With `$('.itdSec')` you are selecting all elements with the class `.itdSec`, however, `prepend` only works on one element.

What you need to do is use [jQuery's .each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over all the selected elements and prepend the title for every single element.

```
$('.itdSec').each(function(i) {
    // 'i' is the index (0,1,2,3...) - not needed here

    // 'this' is now every element in turn
    var title = $(this).data('title');

    $(this).prepend('<div class="itdSecTit">' + $(this).data("title") + '</div>');
});
```

[(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/gnm3o6rv/)

Inside the .each() loop you can then use `this` as the element that is currently being iterated over.

Comment: But prepend does not work on one element, but one element at a time, also you can directly throw a function into prepend to iterate over the elements.